# lowest low after 52 week high afl

Tags: amibroker

Is there a way by using amibroker afl which can find the lowest low made by a stock after it has made a recent 52 week high?
Since this exploration will run on a watchlist, and stocks would have made 52 week high on different dates; how do I code to find lows after each different date of every stock in the watchlist.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can start with this.
[52 Week High AFL](https://www.wisestocktrader.com/indicators/4527-52-week-high-low-for-amibroker-afl)

Then use something like:

```
newLow = LLV(L, BarsSince(HI));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but you wanna use

`LowestSince(new_52_week_high , L, 1);`
where

`new_52_week_high = H > Ref(HHV(H, 250), -1));`